# Renaming Directory with same name different case

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, rename

I am trying to rename a directory in c# to a name that is the same only with differing case.

For example:
f:\test to f:\TEST

I have tried this code:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("f:\\test");
directory.MoveTo("f:\\TEST");
```

and I get a IOException - Source and destination path must be different. I have also tried Directory.Move() with the same result.

How is this done? Do I have to create a separate temp directory, move the contained files from the original directory to the temp directory, and then delete the original, and rename the temp directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you don't need to create a separate directory and move everything. Just rename the folder to something different and then back to the name you want:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\test");
dir.MoveTo(@"F:\test2");
dir.MoveTo(@"F:\TEST");
```

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot more sense than the way I described doing it.

Comment: Actually, `MoveFileEx` doesn't even need that flag to do it; you can even use `MoveFile`, and it works fine. It's the BCL that prevents the rename, not Win32.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the .NET method `DirectoryInfo.MoveTo` throws an exception if the name is the same, you can call the Windows API [`MoveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239) function like this to set the casing of the directory name:

```
bool success = MoveFile(dirInfo.FullName, dirInfo.FullName);
```

With this extern declaration:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool MoveFile(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName);
```

It works fine for me when the name differs in case only. I haven't tried calling it like this when the name is already exactly as specified.

This has the advantage that the directory never disappears under its original name.

It has the disadvantage though that it only works on Windows.

Comment: This works great, but it only affects the actual file/directory and not the root directories (or the directory where the file is located, if moving a file).
So if you need the whole path to conform to the desired name, you need to loop trough all the directories from path to root and check/move each of them to a new name with desired capitalisation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not rename the directory `temp` and then rename again to `TEST` ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes in this case - the file system itself doesn't see the two as different, so you'll need to delete and the add as the new name (or move/delete/move as you suggested)

Comment: The file system itself does. The Windows API wrapper around it introduces case-insensitivity.