# C# Directory Renaming Issue

Tags: c#, directory, renaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming Directory with same name different case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622597/renaming-directory-with-same-name-different-case)

I appear to be running into a rather strange issue. I am using `Directory.Move(oldDir, newDir)` to attempt to rename a series of folders. The issue I seem to be running into is that some of the directories I am renaming are merely just renaming them to the same name only with different cases.

For instance, I have a directory named 'UL17' and I would prefer that all my directories be named in lowercase. So, I have written a routine that will perform the transformation to lowercase, except when I attempt to run the old directory and the new one through the Directory.Move function, it throws an error saying that the new directory must be different from the old one. I am getting pretty frustrated with this because renaming a directory is not supposed to be rocket science.

I'm finding that good old Microsoft as, yet again, managed to take something so tremendously simple and convoluted it into something absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: Could you move it to a temporary (unique) folder, then to the lowercase target?

Comment: I could do that, yes. But it just seems that something Windows can do normally should be able to be achieved through simple program structure rather than going through that extra hassle.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention, Andrew. Sorry for the dup.

Comment: I agree that it's a hassle, but wouldn't worry too much about it.  There are so many other things to complain about with Windows :)

Comment: Hahaha...tell me about it. I just find it so pathetic that Microsoft would take the most simple things and either completely overlook them or screw them up so bad that entirely worthless documentation has to be created just to explain the "master's degree" path that has to be taken to achieve stuff that unix can do without even flinching. Take care, jglouie.

Comment: If you are using windows the file system is not case sensitive by default. This thread
http://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem will be a help.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "c sharp". The language is named "C#".

Comment: @Skittles having just been bitten by this same issue, I agree it's dumb. But it's not as dumb as Unix for having a case sensitive filesystem! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be because you are naming the directory the same name. The case won't matter. What I'd suggest is to rename the directory to, for example from Dir to Dir1, then to dir.

Comment: I suppose I could do that even though I find it far too much effort for something that MS should have thought of in their programming language/s. But I just have to ask the logical question, though. Does that not seem like a rather extraneous amount of work for something that every "normal" operating system would not even bat an eye at?

Comment: @Skittles: turn some of your anger inwards - you're the guy who blames this on Microsoft programming languages when, 1) `Directory.Move` has nothing to do with C# (it's part of .NET), and 2) it should be obvious after a moment's thought that this is an **operating system** feature, not a .NET feature.

Comment: @John, if you paid any attention to my first comment to this person's answer, you would undoubtedly recognize that I AM, in fact, directing my "anger" at the OS and not .NET. *shakes head mildly*

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it from the command line - it won't work there either.  Windows isn't case sensitive - it allows you to use mixed-case naming, but under the covers it ignores casing.

The best workaround is to move your folder to a temporary name, then move it to the new lower case naming.

Comment: Hi Jason. Doing it from the command line would defeat the purpose of my writing a small app to do it. I have a rather large number of directories that I need to operate on and that would like make me want to shoot myself having to manually do all of them one at a time in Windows Explorer or at the command-line.

Comment: No, I was just pointing out that doing it from the command line had the same limitation as doing it from code.  What you're seeing is a limitation of the OS.