# Rename a «grandparent» folder case-sensitive?

Tags: vb.net, windows, case-insensitive

How can I rename the folder called «grandparent» in the following directory structure

`C:\Temp\grandparent\parent\child\`

to «GrandParent» and

`C:\Temp\GrandParent\parent\child\`

The child-folder is not empty and contains different files.

If I try it with the command `IO.Directory.Move(OldDirName, NewDirName)` I get an error that the directory name must not be identical (ignoring the different case spelling).

Do I really have to move it to a completely new temporary directory (like `C:\AnotherTemp\` and then move it back to the desired «GrandParent»?

*([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622597/renaming-directory-with-same-name-different-case) seems only to work, if the last part («child») should be renamed.)*

Comment: I advise using caution. Your question doesn't address why you want case sensitivity, but know that Windows file systems are implemented case *insensitive*. What you see in Explorer is the result of some meta-data, but - unlike POSIX systems - the underlying OS *does not* differentiate between case.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @GojiraDeMonstah. I'm aware that windows is case insensitive. My reason to "rename" or "move" the directoryname is just some kind of better reading.

Comment: The case-insensitive renaming blockade is a .Net thing as can be seen by looking as the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,bd0a671e5d8c491c).  If you call the [MoveFile API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) directly, you can accomplish your goal.